# How to disable the back button in the browser without going back?

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable the back button in the browser without going back? Below is the way that i have tried.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    window.history.forward();
  };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no way to directly disable the back button in a browser. You can aggravate your users into never visiting your site again with an instantly redirecting page, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: The bigger question is: why do you want to disable the back button?!

Comment: why disable the back button?Your best bet is to warn the user:
`window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You work will be lost."; };`

Comment: Lets take the example of a login usecase the user cannot go to the login page after being logged in until he clicks the logout.

Comment: For the login case standard solutions are (1) don't have a login page. When the user attempts to access protected content they are shown the login controls on that page. Then when they login they see that page's content. When going back to the page they see the content. (2) when the user goes back to the login screen they see their profile. Both solutions require some on-load logic to determine what to show.

Comment: I think we have to use ajax call into java script function to relaod the same page if the user click the back button

Comment: So what if **I type `/login.html` manually**!? You cannot prevent me from doing that. "The back button" is the least of your worries. You're barking up the entirely wrong tree for a solution here. What you really want is to control page caching with appropriate caching headers (don't cache login pages) and control the output and redirects on your server based on whether the user is already logged in.

Answer (score -1):

the best thing you can do is:

`window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "your message here"; };`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround to "disable" the back button is create a page that redirects you to the page you want to show after a little time.

For example with this code for the first page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function(){
            window.location.href='secondPage.html';
        },50);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If the user press the back button, the previous page will reopen the desired page.

However, remember that users will hate you for that.